# 3D Viewport to 2D Image

Tags: c#, .net, linear-algebra, raytracing

So here's my viewport class for my very simple ray-tracer.

```
public sealed class ViewPort
{
    public readonly Rectangle3D Rectangle;

    public readonly int Width;
    public readonly int Height;

    public Bitmap Image { get; private set; }

    public ViewPort(Rectangle3D rec, int width, int height)
    {
        this.Rectangle = rec;

        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;

        this.Image = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
    }

    public bool TryRecord(Ray ray)
    {
        Point3D cross;
        if (this.Rectangle.Intersect(ray, out cross))
        {
            this.Image.SetPixel(cross...,ray.Light);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Okay so now how do I map a 3-dimensional point into a two-dimensional image? Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to have the perspective projection formula? or do you want to shade the pixel of your 2D image plane?

Answer (score 0):

As usual for this sort of things, the best is to look at Scratchapixel.com which explains all these concepts in detail. A bit of search on the web I am sure would have pointed you to this amazing resource:

http://scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-1-writing-a-simple-raytracer/